# CSS grid based on data- attributes

Tags: css, grid-layout, angular-material

I've been thinking about the layout system that Angular Material uses, where (by use of directives) they apply simple attributes that create layout:

```
<div layout="row">
    <div flex>One</div>
    <div flex>Two</div>
    <div flex>Three</div>
</div>
```

Beyond being cleaner, they argue that this is a more semantic description of what you are doing in markup compared to something like the Bootstrap way which just applies a bunch of classes:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">One</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">Two</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">Three</div>
</div>
```

Yes, I know flexbox and float-based grids are not the same, the point here is that they are making layouts *attribute*-based rather than *class*-based, leaving styling declarations in the class to be solely dedicated to that item's specific style. I've heard the "Bootstrap is the opposite of semantic" argument a thousand times, and I believe this is intended to provide that ease-of-implementation feel without being non-semantic.

Playing on this concept, we can theoretically do something very similar with CSS:

```
<div data-row>
    <div data-col-xs="4">One</div>
    <div data-col-xs="4">Two</div>
    <div data-col-xs="4">Three</div>
</div>
```

Or you could do `data-flex`, whatever floats your boat. Point is these attributes are valid HTML, works in IE7+, and also follows the theme of making styling in the markup only related to style. The downside here is that it uses the attribute selector, which is slower than classes (marginally, but still).

My questions:

- Is this indeed a more semantic layout method?
- Is being more semantic worth the (albeit small) cost in CSS performance?

I realize this may be delving into opinion, but considering this is the direction of certain things (like Angular Material, and even to an extent Web Components) I think it also is a valid practices question. If you think otherwise and that it should belong on another StackExchange site, let me know and happy to move it.

Comment: The question seems to be inviting discussion so, IMO, **is** off-topic but I'm not sure where in the SE network it would fit but it's not for SO I feel.

Comment: If you are going for a more semantic solution, this is probably better than what it was. But again you are adding code to your HTML that only concerns how you display stuff on the page which is generally not what you want to do, because If you want to change the width of the third column, you would need to change the markup only for visual effects.

Comment: @Paulie_D -> fair enough, I knew it walked that line.

Comment: @Schneeez -> agreed, it certainly makes more sense in the flexbox case than it does in the fixed-width case for this reason, but then the third (hidden) question ... is there a *more* semantic way to do it? I'm all about doing it the best way, so if there is a better way to solve the problem I'd love to learn it.